# Centos gateway пропадают устройства

Tags: linux, centos

Всем привет. На предприятии стоит скада система с gateway сервером на centos. Внезапно на новогодних праздниках 4 января возникла проблема - каждые 2-5 минут пропадает связь с разными устройствами в сети (чаще всего с ИБП, которые опрашиваются по SNMP, но не только они, snmp тоже на gateway сервере) и появляется спустя 2 минуты. В момент потери соединения, устройство не пингуется на gateway, но пингуется на компьютерах. Ранее такая проблема уже возникала полгода назад и при попытке пинга на gateway сервере возникало сообщение «недостаточно буферного пространства». Решилась тогда данная проблема вводом команды:

```
echo 8192 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/neigh/default/gc_thresh3
```

Но теперь это не помогает и устройство поочередно отваливаются и снова появляются. Прошу помощи.

---

Увеличил время опроса в утилите опроса SNMP - не помогло.

---

Благодарю за ответ. gc_thresh уже пробовал корректировать, результата нет. В arp таблице около 1300 записей всегда (что примерно соответствует кол-ву устройств в сети) и буквально 2-3 incomplete записи.
Вот вывод команды dmesg в двух частях. Чуть больше года назад перешли из зоны 172.20 на 172.21, так что видимо в этом логе что-то не очень хорошее происходит, но так было и в эти полгода, когда все работало.
https://pastebin.com/rLynm8Me
https://pastebin.com/dahVpXAG

Comment: Перезагрузка коммутаторов - не помогла. Прошу помощи.

Comment: Проблема все еще не решена. Может кто еще что подскажет.

Comment: И все еще нет решения.

Comment: Arp таблицу чистил, gateway сервер перезагружал, на ИБП 172.21.15.x всех выключил ipv6, хотя он и так на gateway выключен, увеличивал время опроса в SNMP скрипте, игрался с параметрами gc_thresh и прочими связанными с arp, нашел комп 172.21.0.41 на котором стояла прога мониторинга ИБП и он спамил арп запросами на все ИБП, отключил его. Ничего из этого не помогло. Знающий человек подсказал, что дело может быть в большом кол-ве броадкаст запросов, т.к. на всех устройствах, в том числе ИБП маска 255.255.0.0.

Comment: Выкладываю настройки сети с gateway сервера и dump.pcap после tcpdump на интерфейсе bond3 (на нем сидят все 172.21.x.x устройства). Прошу помощи.
https://yadi.sk/d/77-00fOEut4PDg
https://yadi.sk/d/EP22HDiYyW2a5Q

Comment: Пояснение по устройству сети. Есть много электрических подстанций с разными устройствами в разных подсетях с айпи 172.21.x.x (172.21.15.x для ИБП, 172.21.10.x для измерительных приборов и т.д.) с маской 255.255.0.0 и шлюзом 172.21.0.211 (gateway сервер с firewall). Есть в сети обычные компьютеры с айпи 172.21.0.x с той же маской и шлюзом. На подстанции стоит L2 свитч, в который приходят все устройства. Есть серверная в которой стоят несколько опросных свитчей и 2 головных свитча, и gateway сервер в качестве шлюза.

Comment: В момент отвала в скада системе, устройство (чаще всего ИБП, опрашиваемый по SNMP) перестает на 20-30 секунд пинговаться на gateway сервере, но продолжает пинговаться на компьютерах и даже доступ в веб-морду есть. Заметил, что если SNMP скрипт включать, то становится хуже и устройства (даже не опрашиваемые по SNMP) начинают чаще отваливаться. Возможно в этом есть какая-то логика.

Answer (score 1):

Похоже на переполнение очереди буфера сетевого интерфейса. Возможно этот интерфейс попросту перегружен, возможно большие очереди сообщений на / с устройств на этот интерфейс.

Можно попробовать посмотреть что происходит в логах или при помощи `dmesg`

Так же попробовать поиграть с параметрами `sysctl`, как пример:

```
net.ipv4.neigh.default.gc_thresh1 = 80000
net.ipv4.neigh.default.gc_thresh2 = 90000
net.ipv4.neigh.default.gc_thresh3 = 100000
```

P.S. на [форуме](https://forum.sys-adm.in/t/centos-gateway-propadayut-ustrojstva/6751) тоже ответил

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. gc_thresh уже пробовал корректировать, результата нет. В arp таблице около 1300 записей всегда (что примерно соответствует кол-ву устройств в сети) и буквально 2-3 incomplete записи.
Вот вывод команды dmesg в двух частях. Чуть больше года назад перешли из зоны 172.20 на 172.21, так что видимо в этом логе что-то не очень хорошее происходит, но так было и в эти полгода, когда все работало.
https://pastebin.com/rLynm8Me
https://pastebin.com/dahVpXAG